# Merging multiple log files to one single log file

Tags: windows, windows-xp, performance, logging, performance-monitor

I decided to monitor a remote computer (XP SP3) by gathering information with a performance monitor application.

After five days, I stopped monitoring and had 6 log files created by Perfmon.

**My issue is that I want to merge these log files into one single blg or csv log file.**

I used `relog.exe` with this command:

```
relog.exe parviz1.blg parviz2.blg parviz3.blg parviz4.blg parviz5.blg SOparviz6.blg -f BIN -o mergedlogs.blg
```

The result may be seen at: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/200962

**windows problem reports service described:**

Source:  Performance Relogging Utility
Summary:  Stopped working
Date:  11/‎29/‎2012 3:10 AM
Status:  Report sent
Description:  Faulting Application Path:  C:\Windows\System32\relog.exe

Problem signature
 Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
 Application Name:  relog.exe
 Application Version:  6.1.7601.17514
 Application Timestamp:  4ce78d0b
 Fault Module Name:  pdh.dll
 Fault Module Version:  6.1.7601.17514
 Fault Module Timestamp:  4ce7b978
 Exception Code:  c0000005
 Exception Offset:  0002cc4c
 OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
 Locale ID:  1033
 Additional Information 1:  0a9e
 Additional Information 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
 Additional Information 3:  0a9e
 Additional Information 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Extra information about the problem
 Bucket ID:  3279422147

**Any suggestions would be helpful.**

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that:

1. You open each of these log files, right-click on the graph, select "save data as...", and save the log as a csv file.
2. You deal with csv file with whatever text editor you like.